# Vue 2 / Typescript, how to cast a prop inline?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a Vue 2 NuxtJS project setup with Typescript and I'd like to take advantage of the `unknown` keyword in Typescript.

In my component, I receive a prop declared like so

```
props: { 
  items: {
    type: Array as () => LabelValuePair[],
    required: true,
  },
},
```

*LabelValuePair* is declared here

```
interface LabelValuePair {
  label: string;
  value: unknown;
}
```

And inside my template, I'd like to use something like this

```
<li v-for="item in items" :key="item.value as string">
  <span>
    {{ item.label }}: <strong>{{ item.value }}</strong>
  </span>
</li>
```

The thing is, as well as the ternary operator, the `as` Typescript keyword is not recognize as valid syntax by the vue compiler.

Is there a solution or a workaround at least to avoid doing something silly like the following?

```
setup(props) {
  const castItems = props.items.map((item) => ({
    ...item,
    value: item.value as string,
  }));

  return { castItems };
},
```

Comment: How does the script section look like?

Comment: If it's expected to be `string`, why is it typed as unknown? What does happen if you keep it unknown?

Comment: @EstusFlask I have a linting error if I keep it unknown - Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol | undefined'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.ts(2322). runtime-dom.d.ts(1478, 3): The expected type comes from property 'key' which is declared here on type 'ElementAttrs<LiHTMLAttributes>'.

Comment: @EstusFlask I use `unknown` because I can reuse this type with an object as a value instead of a string.

Comment: Then that's a problem that needs to be solved, the type needs to be narrowed down. It would be incorrect to specify anything but string | number | symbol | undefined to a key (and undefined key too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `LabelValuePair` is supposed to be reused and is expected to have `string` value in a prop, this is the case for generic type:

```
interface LabelValuePair<T = unknown> {
  label: string;
  value: T;
}
```

and

```
  items: {
    type: Array as PropType<LabelValuePair<string>[]>,
    required: true,
  },
```

Comment: Awesome! This is indeed a good use case for generics but I completely forgot about them for a second! Thanks for advice